# java - sending variables through nested classes

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I have a class that has a variable of type `Name`.

```
public class Holder {
   private Name name;
   private int snumber;
```

The `Name` class has two strings called `first` and `last` that are assigned values by setter methods. I would like to send over the strings from the `Name` class to name in the `Holder` class, but I'm having trouble doing so. I think I've taken a step in the right direction by doing this

```
public class Holder {
   private Name name;
   private int snumber;

   public void setName(){
      name = new Name();
      name.getFirst();
      name.getLast();
   }
```

but I can't say that I really know what the correct approach is. I also tried `name.setFirst(getFirst)` but that doesn't work. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some context of what you're trying to do? The real situation.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of class `Name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured something out that works.

```
public class Holder {
  private int snumber;
  private Name name;

 public void setName(Name n){
  name=n;
  }
 public Name getName(){
  return name;
}
```

Comment: PROBLEM: "something like '@53a68791' ... when I try to print it from an array slot.  ONE SOLUTION: Override [toString()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/) for the class you wish to print (e.g. "Name").  PS: did you read the article on "nested classes".  *DO* you happen to be using any "inner classes"?

Comment: @paulsm4 another solution that i really should've realized immediately is to specifically get first or last name from within name. i read the article and yea i'm using nested classes. holder and name are only two parts of a larger set of classes that are going to be accessed from one class if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: "Nested class" means "one class is defined within another class's definition".  Yours may or may not be using a "nested class"; the code you've shown so far do *NOT* have any.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you would if the class wasn't nested.

Your setName() method should take a parameter (maybe 2, first and last) and then invoke the name.setFirstName(), name.setLastName() methods.

Right now, your setName() method isn't doing anything.

E.G:

```
public class Holder
{
   private Name name;
   private int snumber;

   public Holder()
   {
       this.name = new Name();
   }

   public void setName(String firstName, String lastName)
   {
      this.name.setFirst(firstName);
      this.name.setLAst(lastName);
   }
}
```

Comment: `NullPointerException`. Perhaps you should create a `Name` object first.

Comment: @dustytrash I've actually never seen the this. before, but I'll see if I can figure it out from here.

Comment: @dustytrash Wouldn't this.name.setFirst(firstname) just send a value back to the setFirst method in the Name class?

Comment: @dustytrash I'm going to read up a bit more and try again later. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good article explaining the relationship between Java inner and outer classes:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_innerclasses.htm

```
class Outer_Demo {
   // private variable of the outer class
   private int num = 175;  

   // inner class
   public class Inner_Demo {
      public int getNum() {
         System.out.println("This is the getnum method of the inner class");
         return num;
      }
   }
}

public class My_class2 {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      // Instantiating the outer class
      Outer_Demo outer = new Outer_Demo();

      // Instantiating the inner class
      Outer_Demo.Inner_Demo inner = outer.new Inner_Demo();
      System.out.println(inner.getNum());
   }
}
```

Note that the example creates instances of both "Outer_Demo" *AND* "Inner_Demo (`outer.new Inner_Demo();`).

Comment: Is it an inner class? The example in the question just shows a regular field of type Name, and doesn't show that Name is an inner class.

Comment: The question was "sending variables through a nested class".  The [tutorialspoint article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_innerclasses.htm) helps answer that question ... and also discusses several inter-related issues.  I encourage the OP to read it.  And yes,the OP's example might not involve a nested class at all.  All the more reason to read the article ;)